# Making lamps work

Tags: darkwood

So I found a lamp in an underground tunnel and brought it back to the house but it won't turn on with the rest of my lamps at night.  Am I doing something wrong to make it turn on or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to several posts you cannot add lamps to the current generator no matter what condition they are in.